# unexpected Identifier return for no forseeable reason

Tags: java, processing

I'm not sure whats going on here I keep getting an unexpected identifier return on my first line of code but I can't tell whats going on is there something wrong with my code or is it my compiler?

```
private static final float IDEAL_FRAME_RATE = 100;

KeyInput currentKeyInput;
GameSystem system;
PFont smallFont, largeFont;
boolean paused;

void setup() {
  size(1360, 640, P2D);
  frameRate(IDEAL_FRAME_RATE);

  // Prepare font
  final String fontFilePath = "Lato-Regular.ttf";
  smallFont = createFont(fontFilePath, 20f, true);
  largeFont = createFont(fontFilePath, 96f, true);
  textFont(largeFont, 96f);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);

  rectMode(CENTER);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);

  currentKeyInput = new KeyInput();

  newGame(true, true);  // demo play (computer vs computer), shows         instruction window
}

void draw() {
  if(keyIsDown(72))
    println("H");
  background(255f);
  background(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  system.run();
}

void newGame(boolean demo, boolean instruction) {
  system = new GameSystem(demo, instruction);
}

void mousePressed() {
  system.showsInstructionWindow = !system.showsInstructionWindow;
}
```

There are six other classes that go with this one if there is nothing wrong with this one could it be due to another lass? If I need to link then I will gladly cause I'm stuck and really want to get this done

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159088/discussion-on-question-by-jonny09-unexpected-identifier-return-for-no-forseeable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've now mentioned that this is in Processing, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language)
where it mentions that "static" is not allowed (you have it at IDEAL_FRAME_RATE at the 1st line, which would explain the error message you were getting)

> Every Processing sketch is actually a subclass of the PApplet[3] Java class (formerly a subclass of Java's built-in Applet) which implements most of the Processing language's features.
>
> When programming in Processing, all additional classes defined will be treated as inner classes when the code is translated into pure Java before compiling. This means that the **use of static variables and methods in classes is prohibited unless Processing is explicitly told to code in pure Java mode**.
>
> Processing also allows for users to create their own classes within the PApplet sketch. This allows for complex data types that can include any number of arguments and avoids the limitations of solely using standard data types such as: int (integer), char (character), float (real number), and color (RGB, ARGB, hex).

Comment: sorry i hadnt realized that it being in proccesing would amke a differance my appologies, so i just cantm make a static variable?

Comment: There is a pure Java mode setting it says, but not sure if OpenProcessing.js port supports such a thing, since it doesn't use the Java plugin

Comment: ok, but before i added the isKeyPressed if statment it ran just fine, did doing that change something?

Comment: Why do you need static in the first place? Do you want to pass data to other classes with it?

Comment: its used throughout the program and its classes i need it to not change and be static also if i just make it a flote without being tatic i get the same error

Comment: Probably unrelated - else removing it / commenting it out would fix the issue

Comment: Can you share your sketch?

Comment: it dose fix the problem but i want to be able to adjust a feature of it by thekey input but i wasnt sure if it would read or that i got the right key code so i set it up to return the letter and thats when i got the error

Comment: Processing is less verbose then Java. There really isn't any reason to use anything other than `float IDEAL_FRAME_RATE = 100;`. `final` isn't idiomatic in most Processing sketches.

Comment: @Jonny09 If you have follow-up questions, please post them as new questions in their own posts. Please also try to isolate your problem to a [mcve] instead of posting your whole project. This answers your first question: Processing doesn't support `static` variables in the top-level sketch, because that doesn't make sense- Processing doesn't use a top-level class, so what would it mean for something to be static?

Comment: guess he is trying to pass data from one class to the other like that, but there should be another way to get the (singular) instance of the running project's class and talk to it (call methods or read/write fields)

Comment: the static variable was part of the source code i saw no reason in adjusting that as i was simply trying to make a game that fit the screen and moved faster and could be made harder so i never needed to pluse most of the classes use the variable and its ever stated anywere else in the program

Comment: @Jonny09 You should [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have modules like VB does (at least last time I checked). So you're missing a class statement to wrap your code I guess.

```
public class SomeClass {
   //...
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: it worked without it prior to me adding in the keyIsDown if statment tho...would that be something that would really cause that?

Comment: In what environment are you working? Probably it places your code in some class. E.g. the "background(...)" isn't something you define, neither do you seem to be using (importing) some other package (namespace), so for it to be working, it must be combining your code with some template.

Comment: im usung the openProccesing enviroment due to any other coding enviroment is blocked by my school's computer